# How do I make the camera move position as the players object becomes bigger in a unity 3d game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my current script it already makes the camera follow the players object. But the players object will get bigger as the game goes on and when it gets to big. It becomes very difficult to see. There are no errors I just don't know how to fix it, and I tried to find it online but I can't.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;

    private Vector3 offset;

    void Start ()
    {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    void LateUpdate ()
    {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends ofcourse on how exactly your player "grows" but you could do something like e.g.

```
void Start ()
{
    offset = (transform.position - player.transform.position) / player.transform.lossyScale.x;
}

void LateUpdate ()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset * player.transform.lossyScale.x * someAdditionalFactor;
}
```

So the offset grows linear together with the size of the player object. Via the `someAdditonalFactor` you could e.g. say if the player grows to double size the offset should be multiplied by 4 (set the factor `2`) or only 1.5 (set the factor `0.5`) .. or just use `1` or leave it out.

---

Alternatively you could directly store and add the offset in the local space of the player using [`InverseTransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) and [`TransformPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html)

```
void Start ()
{
    offset = player.transform.InverseTransformPoint(transform.position);
}

void LateUpdate ()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.TransformPoint(offset);
}
```

This way the offset is calculated automatically when the player changes its scale, rotation or position.

Comment: the problem with that is the player in my game is a sphere, and with that edit to my script it makes the camera roll around when the ball does

Comment: Then you would probably use the upper solution ;)

Comment: You cant use the upper solution because you can't add two Vector3 values

Comment: @PikachuPlays well, yes ofcourse [you can](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_add.html) ... What did you do in your code? ;) Please try it ^^

Comment: Sorry I meant to say you cant multiply the Vector 3 values sorry xD @derHugo

Comment: If you look close I am multiplying/dividing Vector3 and floats which is fine .. again please simply try it ;)

Comment: I DID TRY IT AND IT DIDNT WORK

Comment: That’s why I said those comments. I wasn’t guessing I have looked this up.

Comment: First: DON'T SHOUT! This is conceived as very impolite and if you shout at people trying to help you it might be the last time. Then what did you look up/try exactly? As said `Vector3 + Vector3` is no problem. Neither is `Vector3 * float` .. now look at my calculations `transform.position = player.transform.position + offset * player.transform.lossyScale.x * someAdditionalFactor` this is `Vector3 = Vector3 + Vector3 * float * float` so I don't see the issue here .. please check exactly what you wrote and if there is an error tell us the error instead of `does not work` :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is to scale your offset vector by some value relative to the size of your player character.

```
    void LateUpdate ()
    {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + (offset * GetAdjustmentValue());
    }

    private float GetAdjustmentValue() {

        // Some code to determine the amount you want to shift the camera
        // For example, if your player character is 50% bigger you might
        // want to move the offset 10% further out so you would return 1.1

        // By default, you would return 1, so that no scaling occurs.

        // The details of this calculation really depend on how you are changing
        // the size of your character and what specific effect you want that to have
        // on your camera position
    }
```

Another approach could be to have fixed positions for your camera depending on the character size.  These could be empty GameObjects that are children of your player character.  Then, when your player grows, you could set the camera `transform.position = bigCharacterPositionObject.transform.position`.

Comment: So what code would I put in the function? I get what you mean but how would I make it calculate it via the size of the player?

Comment: It depends on how you're changing the size of your player character.  Are you just scaling it up?  Add the code for that to your question and I can give you some options.

Comment: So how the player scales up depends on the object it absorbs basically if the player is bigger than the object that triggers the function, it absorbs the object and gains 1/5 of its size

Comment: I was more interested in how you had implemented the size increase (i.e. were you directly manipulating the object's localScale and what values were you exposing in doing that) which is why I wanted to see the code.  There are many ways you might implement code to "make a character bigger".